# Scala Slick and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, scala, slick

I'm trying to create a database using Scala and SQLite. I'm using Slick as the library for the SQLite.
I've been googling around for hours and still can't figure out how to get this working. I have eclipse project with Slick installed. I'm trying to instanciate the database with

```
val db = Database.forUrl("url",driver = "org.SQLite.Driver")
```

I have no idea what to put in the url. I'm not very sure about the driver part either. Should I use that one or does "scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver" work too? Or does it even matter?

I'm really confused about all this.Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: There's an example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320819/slick-sqlite-could-not-instantiate-class-tests-sqlitespec-org-sqlite-jdbc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JDBC relies on drivers that implement the JDBC API, and provide access to the low-level functionality of working with particular databases.

URLs are how you tell a JDBC driver which database you want to connect to. The first part of the URL is always `jdbc:<driverId>:`, where `driverId` is the specific name that the driver expects to see (e.g. `postgresql`, `mysql` or, in your case `sqlite`.) The format of the URL after the driver ID is specific to the particular driver implementation.  With mysql and postgres, where you typically connect over TCP to the database server, you'll see a format like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://dbserver:dbport/databaseName

jdbc:postgresql://dbserver:dbport/databaseName
```

But, since SQLite is an in-process, local database, the part of the URL after the driver ID is just a filesystem path, like so:

```
jdbc:sqlite:/home/me/my-db-file.sqlite
```

Comment: How to enable foreign key constraints for sqlite.